# Changing the SourceRect to count forward and backwards through the sprite sheet

Tags: c++, animation, 2d, sprite

Here is my update method that currently cycles through my 6 sprites for a walking character, it counts 0,1,2,3,4,5 and then resets back to 0.

The task is to have it to cycle forwards and then backwards 0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2... etc

I've tried to implement several counting methods to count up and count down given certain conditions, but they appear to fight and loop between frame 4/5.

Is there a quick solution? or would anyone be able to  point me in the direction of a solution please :)

```
    void SpriteGame::Update(int tickTotal, int tickDelta){

    if ( tickTotal >= this->playerLastFrameChange + (TICKS_PER_SECOND / playerSheetLength) )
    {
        this->playerFrame = this->playerFrame + 1;
        this->playerLastFrameChange = tickTotal;

        if (this->playerFrame >= this->playerSheetLength)
        {
            this->playerFrame = 0;
        }

        this->playerSourceRect->left = this->playerFrame * widthOfSprite;
        this->playerSourceRect->top = 0;
        this->playerSourceRect->right = (this->playerFrame + 1) * widthOfSprite;
        this->playerSourceRect->bottom = widthOfSprite;
    }
}
```

implementing the (abs()) method worked counting 0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2.. etc

```
//initializing playerFrame = -4; at the top of the .cpp

this->playerFrame = this->playerFrame +1; //keep counting for as long as its <= 5 [sheet length]

if (this->playerFrame >= this->playerSheetLength)
{
this->playerFrame = -4;
}

this->playerSourceRect->left = (abs(playerFrame)) * widthOfSprite;
this->playerSourceRect->top = 0;
this->playerSourceRect->right = (abs(playerFrame)+1) *     widthOfSprite;
this->playerSourceRect->bottom = widthOfSprite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple way to get it to count up and down continuously would be to run your count from -4 up to 5 (always incrementing). When it goes past 5, set it back to -4.

To get the actual sprite index from that count, just take the absolute of it (`abs()`). That will give you the positive equivalent of any negative values, but leave the positive values unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much, this method works perfectly! i wasn't aware that i could grab the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

How about sth like this:

```
char direction=1; //initialize forward

this->playerFrame+=direction;
if(this->playerFrame >= this->playerSheetLength || this->playerFrame <=0)
  direction*=-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick with the arithmetic approach you've started with you need something like this pseudocode

```
if( /*it's time to update frame*/ )
{
    if( currentFrame >= maxFrame || 
        currentFrame <= minFrame   )
    {
        incrementer *= -1;
    }

    currentFrame += incrementer;
    // Then calculate the next frame boundary based on the frame number

 }
```

Or if you kept a collection of rectangles in a vector, you could simply iterate to end, then reverse iterate to the beginning, and so on.

Google `std::vector, std::vector::begin(), std::vector::end(), std::vector::rbegin(), std::vector::rend()`.

Quick example:

```
vector<rect> vec;
.
.
.
for(vector<rect>::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
{
    ....
}

for(vector<rect>::reverse_iterator iter = vec.rbegin(); iter != vec.rend(); ++iter)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Would there be a more basic (long winded if needs be) way of implementing this? i should probably mention i'm only in my 6th week of my Games Programming course and i need to be able to explain this word for word to the tutor/peers.

Comment: You'll need to get used to the stl someday, but fair enough - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the first answer will help me a lot in 2 weeks when we're re-factoring a lot of our code to simpler, shorter methods :)